# which one is the right way to model this situation?

Tags: uml, entity-relationship

I would like to model the situation of a selling process, in which a number of products are sold and they should appear in an invoice. The question that I have is which it would be the best way to model this situation, it can be:

Article---1------n---Invoice     meaning one article appears in multiple invoices

Article----n-------1--Invoice    meaning one invoice has multiple articles

or

Article-----m-------n-----Invoice

which one is modeled in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the best way to model that is to add an entity between an Invoice and an Article.

[Invoice Article http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/ArticleInvoice.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/ArticleInvoice.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if both can occurr, it is a classical m:n relationship ("has and belongs to many", *habtm*).
In a UML class diagram, there would be 1..* at both ends of the relationship between Article and Invoice.

If you need to annotate any properties to the relationship, then you introduce a third class as a mapping class.